# Premature end of file in META-INF/application.xml

Tags: java, glassfish

I have created a web application through maven 3 and in the project structure there is myartifactid/META-INF/application.xml file. This contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd"
             version="8">

</application>
```

I'm using GlassFish 5 with jdk 1.8.0_191. Whenever I start the server I get the following error (Premature end of file.. Please see server.log for more details. in application.xml):

```
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /usr/applicationserver/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /usr/applicationserver/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
Connected to server
[2018-11-14 11:45:33,345] Artifact myproject: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2018-11-14 11:45:35,767] Artifact myproject: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-11-14 11:45:35,767] Artifact myproject: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [myproject] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/application.xml in archive [myproject].  Premature end of file.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

In Intellij it gives me as an error "Element Application must be declared". Looking arround it seems that this file is used as deployment descriptor for javaeeApplication. In myproject.iml file in Intellij I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="javaeeApplication" name="javaEEApplication">
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <deploymentDescriptor name="application.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/META-INF/application.xml" />
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="web" name="Web">
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <deploymentDescriptor name="web.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
        </descriptors>
        <webroots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web" relative="/" />
        </webroots>
        <sourceRoots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" />
        </sourceRoots>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is that the referenced XML Schemas URL is no longer valid ( http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd )

Comment: This is what I had also in mind, but I'm not sure how to fix it. In https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html#8 I put in the place of the link you provided https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Using `curl -v http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd` I receive a `301 Moved Perm...` With a reference to `http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd`.  running the same `curl -v` command with that URL downloads the correct XML Schema, but I can't get it to validate any docs when referencing the schemaLocation. Feels like the parsers aren't doing something right. This is the [Online Validator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html), I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

The URL in the deployment descriptor is wrong.  All uses of java.sun.com should be xmlns.jcp.org.  If your deployment descriptor was created by a program, please report this bug to the owner of that program.  If your application fails to deploy after correcting this bug, please update your post accordingly.